# Read View's children while initializing View

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

This View is supposed to make a Button for each LinearLayout inside itself, and put that LinearLayout inside a ScrollView. I think the problem is that the LinearLayouts don't exist yet, since they are created AFTER initializing this view. Therefore `getChildCound()` returns zero. You could work around this by hard coding the number of Buttons or getting it from a XML attribute, but you can't put the LinearLayouts in the ScrollViews, when there are no LinearLayouts. Is there a way to work around this?

code:

```
package mika.actual;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class AccordionWidget extends LinearLayout{

    public AccordionWidget(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);

        final Context context = c;

        final int count = this.getChildCount();

        TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.accordion);
        String[] btns = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.buttons);
        ArrayList<LinearLayout> lls = new ArrayList <> (count);

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            View child = this.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof LinearLayout) {
                lls.add((LinearLayout)child);
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < lls.size(); i++){

            if(btns[i] == null){
                Log.e("error: ", "Please add more Button lables to the strings.xml file.");
            }

            final Button btn = new Button(context);
            final LinearLayout ll = lls.get(i);
            final ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(context);
            final int col_pressed = a.getColor(R.styleable.accordion_backgroundColorPressed, Color.BLACK);
            final int col_unpressed = a.getColor(R.styleable.accordion_backgroundColorUnpressed, Color.YELLOW); //Black and yellow, black and yellow...


            LayoutParams btnparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            LayoutParams swparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            LayoutParams llparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            btn.setText(btns[i]);
            btn.setBackgroundColor(col_pressed);
            llparams.weight = 1f;

            btn.setLayoutParams(btnparams);
            ll.setLayoutParams(llparams);
            sv.setLayoutParams(swparams);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            sv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            this.addView(sv);
            this.addView(btn);
            sv.addView(ll);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                private boolean btnstate = false;
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (btnstate) {
                        btn.setBackgroundColor(col_pressed);
                        sv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btnstate = true;
                    } else {
                        btn.setBackgroundColor(col_unpressed);
                        sv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btnstate = false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        a.recycle();
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mika.actual.AccordionWidget
    xmlns:accordion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    accordion:text_color="@color/text_color"
    accordion:backgroundColorPressed="@color/button_pressed"
    accordion:backgroundColorUnpressed="@color/button_not_pressed"
    android:id="@+id/swaggy"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="yolooooo yooo"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="yolooooo yooo"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="yolooooo yooo"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="yolooooo yooo"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="yolooooo yooo"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</mika.actual.AccordionWidget>
```

Comment: Try this http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-create-custom-layout-in-android-by-extending-viewgroup-class

Comment: @KonstantinsBogdanovs I don't really understand what's on the site. I'm new to android.

Comment: Why dont't you create custom widget using laoyoutIndlater? Then you can do something like:
<cusomWidget>
  <Tetview or whatever/>
</customWidget>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that you need to put your logic into `onLayout`
Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
final Context context = c;

    final int count = this.getChildCount();

    TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.accordion);
    String[] btns = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.buttons);
    ArrayList<LinearLayout> lls = new ArrayList <> (count);

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        View child = this.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof LinearLayout) {
            lls.add((LinearLayout)child);
        }
    }
.......
```

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onLayout(boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Make sure that you call `child.layout()` for each child inside this method.

Comment: what does `child.layout()` do?

Comment: It places child into ViewGroup

Comment: So basically I have to call `child.layout()` instead of `parent.addView(child)`?

Comment: Yes. And you should do it inside onLayout method

Comment: Thank you my friend. I ended up not using the `layout()` method, but just calling `super.onLayout()`. But your idea helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom LinearLayout inside ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/parent"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Then Create java class for your layout and inflate it.

See [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html)